# Play sound through 2 HDMI outputs

Tags: arch-linux, kde, manjaro, plasma

I have 2 monitors, and when I used Windows I could use voicemeeter to play audio through both at once.

Is there an alternative for Manjaro, or a way to do it using the default sound applications?

Comment: Assuming Manjaro runs Pulseaudio (likely), and assuming you actually get two different ALSA devices for each HDMI output (which may be the hard part), it's easy to do with a Pulseaudio module.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Audio** in the System Settings, click **Advanced**, then toggle "Add virtual output device for simultaneous output on all local sound cards".

Unfortunately, this does not work if you want output to play on some devices but not others.